# Can I find a closed form of $\int f(z) dz$ in terms of $f(z)$ and $g(z)$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I will define a real function $f$ where $f'(a)=f(g(a))$ for all possible inputs $a$. I want to find the integral of $f(z)$ in terms of $f(z)$, $g(z)$, $f^{-1}(z)$, $g^{-1}(z)$, and derivatives of these functions. I'll show what I've tried. I'm assuming $g^{-1}(z)$ exists

$$\int f(z) dz$$
$$g(u)=z,\space\space g'(u)du=dz,\space\space u=g^{-1}(z),\space\space du=\frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(z))}$$
$$\int f(g(u))g'(u)du=\int f'(u)g'(u)du$$
$$a=g'(u),\space\space da=g''(u),\space\space c=f(u),\space\space dc=f'(u)du$$
$$f(u)g'(u)-\int f(u)g''(u)du$$
After this step I'm not sure what to do. I haven't been to calculus class yet, but I've been studying on my own online and self study from a calculus book my old math teacher gave me. No one I know can help me with this because they didn't really ever learn calculus, and most of them hate math.

I would like to know if there is a closed form and how to get there from here.

Comment: why would there be a closed form have you tried to prove there isn't one?

Comment: @SuperWarm I have no clue how to do that, and I know it can be done using $f(z)$ when $f(g(z))=z$, I saw it in a video.

Comment: @SuperWarm I also tried examples for $f(z)$ like when $g(z)=2x+1$ and I do get a result using this method.

Comment: What are the properties of $g$? Is it injective? If not then you can't make a change of variables that way a priori, and $g^{-1}$ isn't defined. Same for $f$. Also, is $z$ a real or a complex number?

Comment: What do you understand about integration?

Comment: @Teancum I understand how to use u substation and I know how to integrate by parts, that the basics of what I know.

Comment: I think that no madder what direction you will have to have an integral of the nth derivative of f and the mth derivative of g. At least that what I could do just using u substation and integrate by parts

Comment: @Teancum can you prove it?